# How do I get to Zora's Domain?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I am stuck on The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time on 3DS. I am at Lake Hylia and there appears to be a temple under the lake. From what the owl said and online guides I'm supposed to play Zelda's Lullaby somewhere but I've tried loads of places all around the lake and got nothing so far.

There is an island with a stone that says "When water fills the lake, shoot for the morning sun." I have tried shooting the slingshot between the two pillars, at the sun, and playing Zelda's Lullaby there.

I'm just baffled because there is zero clues as to what to do next...

Comment: "When water fills the lake, shoot for the morning sun." - Wait till you come back as an adult and beat the Water Temple, then try this again; This prophecy is for Adult Link only.

Comment: @RavenDreamer You don't need to wait to beat the water temple to get the fire arrows. You just need to shoot at the sun anytime it's rising. To obtain them before beating the water temple you will need to use the scarecrows song and the longshot.

Comment: @Wipqozn - which is sort of a moot point, since the longshot is *in* the Water Temple.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Still, you can get it before beating the water temple. I wasn't saying you were wrong exactly, just pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hint from the owl is to enter Zora's Domain. The entrance to the path to Zora's Domain is in Hyrule field near the entrance to Kakariko Village. Make your way to the end of the path where you will find the Triforce symbol he's referring to.

Just so you know, you can also go fishing in Lake Hylia. Also, when looking at your map subscreen the flashing dot is where to go next.

Comment: OK thanks I found it now, but I don't get what the point of going to Lake Hylia was (the owl said to go there). And a water creature there says "I am a Zora" which confused things even further. Thanks for the tip about the map though, never realised that before (the map very badly designed).

Comment: @Disgruntled - It's been a while since I played the game, but perhaps the Owl mentioned that the waters of Zora's Domain flow into Lake Hylia?

Comment: @Raven: That is mentioned in Zora's Domain. After you get the scale to be able to dive deeper, you need to go back to Lake Hylia to get the letter in a bottle there.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This dungeon cannot be entered until after you get the Master Sword and is intended to be done after the Forest Temple.

The island isn't related to the temple.  It's used to get an optional item once you have the Bow.

In order to enter the Water Temple, you need the Iron Boots and Zora Tunic.

The Zora Tunic can be obtained from either King Zora or from one of the shops in the game.

The Iron Boots are located in the ice cavern near Zora's Domain.